# Result from derivatives seem inconsistent

Tags: integration, derivatives, physics

I'm working on a physics problem that looks like this

For some context we have a person on his sled represented in our first term. The second term represents the velocity of a stone thrown backwards

$$ (m_p + m_s)\frac{dv_s}{dt} + m\frac{v_{st}}{dt} = 0 $$

The answer:
$$ (m_p + m_s)v_s(t) + mv_0 = 0$$

where $v_0$ means the inital velocity of the throw

I cannot understand why the answer is not this:

$$ (m_p + m_s)v_s(t) + mv_{st}(t) = 0$$

i assume it if we were interested in $v_{st}(t)$ we could do this:

$$ (m_p + m_s)v_{s0} + mv_{st}(t) = 0$$

Comment: The derivative is $0$, so the expression is *constant*. Evaluate the constant.

Comment: What does $m\frac{v_{st}}{dt}$ mean?

Comment: the st subscribt is for stone, so it is the force of the stone.